# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. I don’t know how to fix this

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

While logging in I am facing following error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
>
> (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider).

There are two accounts on my PC. It works fine when I login into SQL server through my administrator account but when I try to login into SQL server through my second account it shows the above error.
And I want to tell that someone posted the same problem on this website and I followed the solution but that did not work for me.

Comment: Are you logging in with SQL Server Management Studio or via some code?

Comment: SQL server management sutdio

Comment: Check the error log by running  `sp_readerrorlog`

Comment: add summary of the outcome `sp_readerrorlog` to your question.